# Two LEDs but they are different in brightness

Tags: circuit-design

I have duplicated the circuit below where the TTL side is a XBee Radio.  The LEDs on TTL TX and RX are the same part number, the resistors are the same value and they are being driven by the same VCC level.  The problem I am having is that when they are biased, the TX is much brighter than the RX, which is barely noticeable.  I have searched and have not found an answer...maybe I'm not searching for the right thing?

Can anyone explain why they are different in brightness?

[image]

Comment: You have no control over the input voltages, so connecting an LED to them directly is not wise.

Comment: The input voltages, according to the XBee datasheet is 3.3v.

Comment: The nominal value doesn't help you. You need it to be guaranteed to be at least a particular value given a particular load. Did you measure it with the LED loading it? Was it 3.3?

Comment: Would there be a better setup that will accomplish the same task of indicating status?

Comment: With the size of your base resistor (R4), you may not be turning Q2 all of the way on. It may not be sinking enough current to light LED2 as much as you would like.

Comment: Mark, the only reason I question that is Q1 has the same base resistance.  Maybe R2 is the cause?

Comment: @SolveEtCoagula07 Ideally, you would use a transistor to light the LEDs with the TX/RX line connected to its base.

Comment: I agree with David Schwartz, use transistors as LED switches.  Then if there is a difference you can look at your resistor tolerances.

Comment: But Q1 doesn't need to pass as much current. The RS232 load is many times smaller then the load of an LED.

Comment: With serial ports, the brightness of the LEDs connected to Tx and Rx will vary with the signals being sent as the pulse width of the signal will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is Q2, the buffer transistor on the RS232 Tx/TTL Rx line. Both Q1 and Q2 provide signal inversion, but only the TTL Rx line is being driven by your buffer.

RS232 uses a default high voltage level to indicate a logical zero, so ordinarily (when there is no data being transmitted) TTL Tx and RS232 Tx are physically high. Since TTL Tx is high, there is little drop across the LED and resistor, so the LED is dim. The TTL Rx, though, is being pulled to ground by Q2, so there is full voltage across the LED.